# How to Vlookup from non-static tab references?

Tags: excel

I have a excel file with tabs having prices from different food shops a,b,c,d,e,f,g.....etc.

I want to perform a lookup from another tab called "Food List" that has all the items I want to buy in it. Now the list also has a column with the shop in it so might look like:

SHOP TAB - ITEM DESCRIPTION

A - Eggs

B - Bread

D - Milk

and so on.

Is there a way to VLOOKUP the price from the respective shops?

So

```
=VLOOKUP("Item Description", "Shop Tab", "Price from Shop Tab",0)
```

An example of this would be

```
=VLOOKUP(Eggs,"A","Price")
```

Then I want to copy the formula down and it to calculate

```
=VLOOKUP(Bread,"B","Price")
```

The problem is I don't know how to make the reference to the shop tab depend on the row in the list?

Comment: Your question seems a bit fuzzy to me but I think you're looking for the [indirect function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261). You can use it like this: `VLOOKUP(value_to_search,INDIRECT("SHOP TAB - "&A2),col_index,FALSE)` (assuming the value you need is in A2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

> **[INDIRECT FUNCTION](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)**

In my example, I have created 3 ListObjects (tables) in 3 different tabs (or worksheets). They are all the same, except the price. And the name of each table is `Tabla1`, `Tabla2` and `Tabla3`. Each table has same products but with price 1, 2 or 3 euro, depending on table.

[image]

Now, I have a final sheet where I invoke each product, but one from each *shop* (that would be from each ListObject).

[image]

As you can see, I'm getting the price from different sources, using `INDIRECT`. My formula is:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2;INDIRECT(A2);2;0)
```

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

**UPDATE:** To set the name of a ListObject, just select any cell inside the range, and go *Design tab, and top left you should be able to change ListObject name:

[image]